# ChainID solidity version 0.6.12

Tags: constructor, solidity, smartcontracts

I've seen this code working in many factory contracts:

```
constructor() public {
    uint chainId;
    assembly {
        chainId := chainid
    }
    DOMAIN_SEPARATOR = keccak256(
        abi.encode(
            keccak256('EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract)'),
            keccak256(bytes(name)),
            keccak256(bytes('1')),
            chainId,
            address(this)
        )
    );
}
```

However, this works when I use
`pragma solidity =0.5.16;`
But if I use `pragma solidity =0.6.12;`, I get an error:

`ParseError: Expected '(' but got '}' } ^`

I tried to do the following:

```
constructor() public {
    uint chainId;
    assembly {
        chainId := chainid()
    }...
```

But then I get multiple errors on variables and functions saying:

`TypeError: overriding public state variable is missing string public constant name = ...`

How do I write the assembly line in solidity version 0.6.12?

Thank you,

Using version 0.5.16 it's not an option because many imports use 0.6.12 and they won't work...

Answer (score 3):

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity =0.6.12;

contract Test {

string public constant name = "Your Contract name";    

constructor() public {
uint chainId;
assembly {
        chainId := chainid()
    }
bytes32 DOMAIN_SEPARATOR;
DOMAIN_SEPARATOR = keccak256(
    abi.encode(
        keccak256('EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract)'),
        keccak256(bytes(name)),
        keccak256(bytes('1')),
        chainId,
        address(this)
    )
);}}
```

Try this. If you upgrade your code to version 0.8.0 and above there is a variable available in global namespace called
`block.chainid`